# How can I know that my question is duplicate from the heading of a question and what should i do if my question is marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

How can i know that my question is duplicate from a heading of the question?

And if we use mobile then it don't show the same questions when we type our heading of the question.

And what we should do if our question is marked as duplicate question?

Should we delete our question or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i know that my question is duplicate from a heading of the question?

You really can't because just because the title *sounds* similar doesn't mean they are dupes. You need to search multiple keywords that are similar and see if there is one which answers your question.

> And if we use mobile then it don't show the same questions when we type our heading of the question

I'm not sure about this but I would never try to post a question on a mobile device (maybe a big tablet). But, to ask a good/quality question, this would be a pain.

> And what we should do if our question is marked as duplicate question?
>
> Should we delete our question or what?

Only if it is a low quality question which should be deleted anyway. Otherwise, it serves as a signpost to the target dupe. People searching certain, related terms may find your which would lead them to the duplicate.

Comment: _"Otherwise, it serves as a signpost to the target dupe."_ That's a very good point.

Comment: If question is marked as duplicate then is there any chance that i will be blocked for posting question in future?

Comment: I don't know how the system calculates it but as long as you don't have a whole lot it's nothing to worry about. But a simple search of a few key words normally will bring up any obvious duplicates

Comment: You only have one dupe and a few downvotes with a few upvotes so I wouldn't worry too much right now. FYI: deleting posts counts against you also so you don't want to be doing too much of that.

Comment: Thank you @codeMagic for explaining me!!! :)